# How to prevent font-family and font-size inheritance

Tags: html, css

The font-family and font-size of my project are being inherited even when I specify !important.

You can see the issue when you hover over the first link. There's a label in the top right corner, but I want the font to be times new roman, 12px, and white. So completely different than the font from the rest of the project.

However, when I edit the ".album-art .film" CSS selector, which should control the label, the font doesn't change.

https://codepen.io/cjk47/project/live/4fdb73a9558a26a6c1a0a31c6c31705d

```css
.tracks {
  margin-top: 46px;
}

li.track {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

li.track:hover {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #18181b;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;
}

li.track:hover .album-art {
  display: block; 
}

.album-art {
  z-index: -10; 
  position: fixed; 
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50%;
  max-height: 450px;
  display: none; 
  opacity: 0.5;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.album-art img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.album-art .film {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="logo">
    <img src="/img/logo1.png" height="50" width="50">

  </div>

  <div class="tracks">

    <ol>
    <li class="track">
      <a href="#" class="nav">
        <div class="album-art"><img src="/img/king-princess.png"><span class="film">Film</span></div>
        <p class="track-name">King Princess - 'Cheap Queen'</p>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="track">
      <a href="#" class="nav">
        <div class="album-art"><img src="/img/charly-bliss.png"></div>
        <p class="track-name">Charly Bliss - 'Capacity'</p>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="track">
      <a href="#" class="nav">
        <div class="album-art"><img src="/img/julia-jacklin.jpg"></div>
        <p class="track-name">Julia Jacklin - 'Good Guy'</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <ol>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want the label text when hovering over the first link to be times new roman, 12px, and the color white. However, right now when I try to do this, my stylings are being overridden by the default fonts.

Comment: It's actually working. Just hard to read. Increase the font size on your span and you will see.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, plumwd. I just did that but the text still has a weird black border around it, which makes it illegible.

Comment: It's just a poor font choice I think... there's not much you can do if you insist on Times.

Comment: Remove the black background from your span and then change the color of your font. The white will be hard to read on a light background.